# 1999 Dodge Durango

Tags: troubleshooting, dodge, durango

I was driving yesterday at 35 mph, all of a sudden  RPM went straight to 0. I noticed through out the day the RPM would fluctuate. When the RPM dropped everything locked up but I still had power. And the vehicle is an automatic. What might cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the Check Engine Light (CEL) on? If so, have you had the codes read? Really, your question doesn't give us much to go on, so we'll need a lot better information as to what's going on to give you a coherent answer.

Comment: Also, what does "everything locked up" mean?  Needs more detail.